Google Firebase sign in won't work after adding StateChanged on my code in Unity. The email and password sign in does work
I'm working on an app, it is working with Firebase authentication both email/password and google auth. The google auth stopped working when I implemented the state changed of the user, but I can't find the error.
I wanted to store the state of the user (if it is logged in or if it isn't) because I want the app to open on my second scene when the user already signed in, and I want it to open in my first scene when the user is not signed in. My code worked normally (but it always opened on the first scene) and after I implemented some code related to the state changed of the user, my google sign in sopped working but my email/password keeps working and, it indeed stores the states and opens as I expected it to. What happens is that, when I press the google button, it loads as it if were going to load the google accounts where I select one to sign in, but it never happens, nothing opens, it doesn't move from the first scene.
This is my code, remember that the lines that are having trouble with my google sign in are the ones related to this FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;.
As I'm working on unity, I can't try my app on my pc because the google sign in doesn´t work in the unity interface. I tried to see what was happening with the android logcat that unity has, but it doesn't show me an error, it says lots of thing but none of them are errors.
Thank you for your help.


public class emailPassLogin : MonoBehaviour
{

    //Google
    public string GoogleWebAPI = "MY API"; //here is my api working, i didn't uploaded here because i don't know if that's a way to steal my firebase project or somethin like that

    private GoogleSignInConfiguration configuration;
    DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = DependencyStatus.UnavailableOther;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseUser user;
    


    

    private void Awake()
    {

        configuration = new GoogleSignInConfiguration
        {
            WebClientId = GoogleWebAPI,
            RequestIdToken = true
        };


       //here is all of my UIToolkit inicialization

        FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;

    }

    private void Start()
    {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        AuthStateChanged(this, null);
      
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (auth != null)
        {
            auth.StateChanged -= AuthStateChanged;
        }
    }

    private void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {

        if (auth.CurrentUser != null)
        {
            // User is signed in, navigate to the app
            Debug.Log("User is signed in.");
            EnterInApp();
        }
        else
        {
            // User is signed out, stay on the login screen
            Debug.Log("User is signed out.");
            SceneManager.LoadScene("LogRegScene");
        }
    }


    #region signup 

//my sign up is working fine
   #endregion

    #region Login email password
   //this is working fine
    #endregion

    #region Google
    void GoogleSignInClick(ClickEvent evt)
    {
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration = configuration;
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration.UseGameSignIn = false;
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestIdToken = true;
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestEmail = true;

        //GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn().ContinueWith(OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished);
        if (GoogleSignIn.Configuration == null)
        {
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration = configuration;
        }
        Debug.Log("Calling SignIn Google");
         try
        {
            Debug.Log("GoogleSignInClick: Intentando iniciar sesión con Google");
            GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn().ContinueWith(OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished);
            Debug.Log("GoogleSignInClick: Se ha llamado a GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn()"); 
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            
            Debug.LogError("Singin width google Exception:" + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished(Task<GoogleSignInUser> task)
    {

        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Fault");
        }
        else if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Login Cancel");
        }
        else
        {
           Debug.Log("OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished: Autenticación exitosa"); .
            Credential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(task.Result.IdToken, null);
Debug.Log("OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished: credenciales traídas"); //The code reaches HERE
            auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialASync was canceled");
                    return;
                }
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialASync encountered an error");
                    return;
                }
                
                user = auth.CurrentUser;

                lb_warningSignUp.text = "Inicio de sesión exitoso";            
                EnterInApp();


            });
        }
    }

    void EnterInApp()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Scenes/UI2");
    }

  


    #endregion

}

Now I know what's happening, for some reason my code isn't entering this function at all, but the lines above are working fine:
auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
           {
               Debug.Log("OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished: entró al SignInWithCredentialAsync ");
               if (task.IsCanceled)
               {
                   Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync: Fue cancelado");
                   return;
               }
               if (task.IsFaulted)
               {
                   Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync: Encontró un error");
                   foreach (var e in task.Exception.InnerExceptions)
                   {
                       Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync: Error: " + e.Message);
                   }
                   return;
               }

               user = auth.CurrentUser;

               lb_warningSignUp.text = "Inicio de sesión exitoso";
               Debug.Log("SignInWithCredentialAsync: Inicio de sesión de Google exitoso");
               EnterInApp();
           });


Welcome to SO. That is a LOT of code for use to parse through. Best practice is to limit the code to where the trouble is. Some basic troubleshooting will help narrow that down. Add a breakpoint and step through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected. Then update the question with which line, what was expected and then what the actual result was.

Good update, but a bit more debugging and info will help narrow the issue. The question states that auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync is not entering. Does that mean the code gets to the function but the calls inside it do not work? Or does it mean it never gets to that function at all? Does this Debug.Log("OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished output? How about Debug.Log("OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished: entró al SignInWithCredentialAsync ");?

thank you so much for your answers!  it never gets to that function at all, this line never happens: Debug.Log("OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished: entró al SignInWithCredentialAsync "); and that happened after I incorporated the AuthStateChanged method!

Per my first comment, adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line will be revealing. Narrowing down where the code is not working is very important; does this line Debug.Log("OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished: Autenticación exitosa"); get called? If not then this function void OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished is not being called. That troubleshooting step would really help and eliminate this kind of interactive debugging, which as you can see, SO is not well suited for.

Yes, that line of code gets called! And I'm gonna try to do what you said about adding a breakpoint, because the OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished is being called! I don't know why my code is dying after that. I'm gonna try to do some real debugging, thank you so much for your help!
